# Mario Kart 8 DLC Question

Tags: mario-kart-8

I'm thinking of pre-ordering the Mario Kart 8 DLC soon. Something I want to know is that in the event I want to cancel the pre-order of the DLC, for whatever reason it may be, can I do it via e-mail on the Nintendo Customer Service page of their website, or is it just by phone? I've had a look and can't find an option to do it via e-mail.

Comment: If you have a separate question to ask, ask it in another question.

Comment: And if your question is "If I pre-order than cancel, do I get the keep the extra colors of Yoshi and Shy Guy?" then I recommend you not try to scam the system.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what Nintendo's pre-order policies are, and how to contact them.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Nintendo's page for Mario Kart 8 DLC](http://mariokart8.nintendo.com/dlc/):

> You can cancel your advance purchase by contacting Nintendo Customer Service before the first DLC pack is released.

Clicking 'Support' near the top of that page, selecting Wii U, and then 'Contact Us', leads to [this support page](http://www.nintendo.com/corp/contact.jsp), which lists `1-800-255-3700` as the contact for Order Problem Solving.

So, yes, you have to call via phone to cancel an order. Email does not appear to be an option.